# Video rotated 90 degrees in Android when using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rotation, mediarecorder

I record .mp4 using MediaRecorder in android. I made it slow down using android4ffmpeg lib and then video(.mp4) was rotated 90 degree. How do I fix it?

If use .mp4(recorded by phone camera in android), not rotate! But use MediaRecorder it always rotated 90 degree.

command is

```
String[] complexCommand = { "ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "", "-strict",
        "experimental", "-filter_complex",
        "[0:v]setpts=4.0*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]", "-map", "[v]",
        "-map", "[a]", "-b", "2097k", "-r", "60", "-vcodec", "mpeg4",
        "" };
```

mediarecorder is

```
            recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(sufaceHolder.getSurface());
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            recorder.setOutputFile(inFileName);
//          recorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
```

Comment: meta-data was changed while encoding. i fixed it! for ffmpeg

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. How did you fix it?

Comment: Vaeianor // use ffmpeg!

Comment: I was using ffmpeg. The only way for me to fix it was to re-encode the video. But I don't want to re-encode the video as it takes too long.

Comment: I am also facing the Same problem, Can you please share your code that fixed this Problem. Thanks

Comment: @user2098010 Will you tell me how did fix in FFMPEG ?

Comment: Salman Khakwani// ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vf transpose=1 -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k /sdcard/video_output/out.mp4